# net files /close does not work as expected

Tags: powershell

We have many self-written applications which are executed in a network location. Whenever a developer wants to publish a new version of this application, I have to close all opened files on the server where the app is located, by going to:

```
computer management > Shared Folders > Opened Files
```

then choose all the files of the application - right click and close.

I want the developers to do that by themselves via PowerShell, so I wrote a `Unlock-Files` function. This part of the function should close the files, with the `net files $id /close` call:

```
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $workpath, $server {

    param($workpath,$server)
    $list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    $adsi      = [adsi]"WinNT://./LanmanServer"
    $resources = $adsi.psbase.Invoke("resources") | % {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            ID        = $_.gettype().invokeMember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)
            Path      = $_.gettype().invokeMember("Path","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)
            OpenedBy  = $_.gettype().invokeMember("User","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)
            LockCount = $_.gettype().invokeMember("LockCount","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)
        }
    }

    $resources | ? { $_.Path -like $workpath } | tee -Variable Count | % { 
            $id = $_.ID
            net files $id /close > $null
            if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { $list.add("File successfully unlocked $($_.path)") > $null }
            else { $list.add("File not unlocked (maybe still open somewhere): $($_.path)") > $null }
    }

    if (!( ($count.count) -ge 1 )) { $list.add("No Files to unlock found in $workpath on $server") > $null }
    $list

}
```

I expect `net files /close` to behave the same way as the manual way I do directly on the server described above, but it doesn't behave like this at all. It sometimes closes the file, sometimes not. But it never closes all the necessary files, so the developer can not publish his application. also, `net files` almost never finishes with `LastExitCode 0`, but I can't get my head around why.

- Is there a way to force `net files` to really close all the files?
- why would `net files` behave different than closing the files manually?
- Is there a native PowerShell way to do this?
- Is there a list of last exit codes, so I can wrap my head around this issue further?

Thank you!

Comment: You should post the exit codes you get otherwise this becomes a guessing game. Perhaps another solution might be to rename the files, copy the new ones and let the old ones phase out when everyone closes the application.

Comment: Don't deploy "over the top" of an existing install. Install alongside e.g. in a folder named to match the version number. You can then have a single entry point (e.g. shortcut file) that you just overwrite with the new details. This would mean any _new_ connections are in the new version.